# Incorrect mime type when serving javascript from Go

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a go template file that renders my HTML & data from the server successfully. I, however, want to create a search and filter functionality with Vue and possibly Vuex by passing data from the Go file as props to a Vue component (kindly correct me if I'm wrong on choosing this way). I have created three files:

vue_func.js which contains the following:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  delimiters: ['{%', '%}'],
  
  data() {
    return {
      name: "World!"
    };
  },
  
});
```

A dronemodel.js file which contains HTML that is supposed to render a list of drones and is basically this way :

```
const models={
template:`<myhtml>`
}
```

then I'm exporting this constant:

```
export{models}
```

I'm then trying to import this to vue_func.js:

```
import {models} from './components/dronemodels'
```

and trying to use it as:

```
Vue.component("models", models);
```

This setup throws this error:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
> the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type
> checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

What could be the issue? The same happens when i try to import my store.js (Vuex) to a my vue instance which is at vue_func.js.

Comment: If you suspect an issue with your Go code, please edit your question to include the relevant Go source. If not, please remove the `go` tag.

Comment: My bad, i don't think it is a go problem. Tag removed.